# Send url to iframe via jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to send a url to an iframe using an ajax call, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr(id);
      // Need to send the URL below to the iframe
      // http://www.example.com/?list_id=id    
  });
});
</script>

<iframe name="get_data"></iframe>

<div class="clickme" id="3453">Click Here</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("iframe[name='get_data']").prop("src", "http://www.example.com/?list_id=" + id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr(id);
      $('iframe[name="get_data"]').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/?list_id=' + id);

  });
});
```

if you are using jquery `1.6` or higher use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (as stated by Andrew Whitaker )

```
$("iframe[name='get_data']").prop("src", "http://www.example.com/?list_id=" + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').attr('src', url);
```

You probably want a better selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just get a handle on the `iframe` and set its `src` attribute:

```
$('iframe[name="get_data"]').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/?list_id=' + id);
```